# Django static fails only on development?

Tags: django, file, static, http-status-code-404

Deployed site works great! however when I run the development server it does not load the statics. when accessing

```
localhost:9090/static
```

it returns 404 page not found and says:

```
Directory indexes are not allowed here.
```

Please help!

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/mysite/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/
DEBUG = True
```

tried:

```
-collectstatic method
-adding static_dir & urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Django but, what I do have in my settings(and static files work) is the following:
(I do have a folder called static in the top directory of my project)

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/path/to/static/',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from yourprojectname import settings
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # url(r'^$', 'yourprojectname.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/$', blog),
)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

In settings.py

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'static'), # if you name your static files folder is named as 'static'
)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'template'),
)
```